# Bootstrap navbar not expending as expected (at the bottom of the navbar)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to customize a bootstrap navbar, and now I have a problem when expending the menu.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51ywny19/2/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="halp">Help ?</a>
      <!-- Placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- the collapsing menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <!-- pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menu active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->

  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when clicking on the collapsed square. it expends 'inside' the navbar.

How could I make it expand like the examples given on the bootstrap website :

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

EDIT :

I case of someone got the same problem : after experimenting with the changes made by Flopet17 (thank you btw), the problem is caused by the 'pull-left' class at the header div (3rd line). When I remove it, it all works well.

Case closed I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a bit the original code, removed what you don't need and added `pull-left` class and now it looks like this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/51ywny19/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Just move your collapsing menu outside of the `.container`.

Here is working copy --> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/51ywny19/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your solution create another problem.

When using a larger screen, the whole menu is under the 'brand'